# Dividing a large printing job into multiple smaller jobs

Tags: printing

Let's say I want to print a `1,000 page document` using one printer. My understanding is that, while the `1,000 pages` printing job takes place, nothing else can be printed.

I would like to enable other users to print their documents while the `1,000 pages` document is being printing. One way to do this is to create 20 smaller printing jobs of 50 pages each. In this case, users will be able to queue their printing jobs in between the smaller printing jobs.

Is there a way to do this? Maybe an automated way that doesn't require manually splitting the document and printing each part separately?

Comment: If you piled all 20 smaller jobs into the queue, they'd be processed in order, no?  How do you imagine solving the problem?

Comment: I imagine that jobs would only go into the queue only after the previous 50 page job finished.

Comment: So you'd have the person with the 1000-page print job wait until each smaller job is done printing before submitting the next job? Or, more specifically, wait for the print queue to be empty?

Comment: this is going to be very difficult and will probably involve splitting of the file into 1-page parts or the equivalent thereof regardless plus some sort of print queue or printer monitoring to try to see where the queue or printer is (this will depend on the printer or print queue software...). probably easier to a) buy a printer for the big jobs or b) let folks know when big jobs happen and they can wait

Comment: What do you mean with "while the 1,000 pages printing job takes place". There is no way to avoid that the printer gets busy putting text on each physical page. If you want to stop and re-start, then the question becomes: who will move the already printed pages to some other place and will put the pages back so the printing job could continue? The only other solution could be that the printer has several output bins and could place the printed pages on each separate bin until the user picks them up. No, not any easy solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a text file called `pages.txt` that include the ranges of pages that you would like to print at a time, as follows:

```
1-50
51-100
101-150
151-200
. . . .
. . . .
```

The command `lpr` will enable you to send printing orders to the printer, for more information about the command please check `lpr` -[man](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/lpr.1.html).

In order to automate the work,  you can use something like:

```
#!/bin/bash
while IFS= read line 
do

    lpr -P <my_printer_name> -o page-ranges=$line
    sleep 10

done <pages.txt
```

If you would like to make time-gaps between the prints, you can use the command `sleep` after `lpr` (e.g. `sleep 10` seconds in the previous bash).

If you would like to be notified by email once your printing job is completed, you can use the command `mail` after `done <pages.txt` something like:

```
#!/bin/bash
while IFS= read line 
do

    lpr -P <my_printer_name> -o page-ranges=$line
    sleep 10

done <pages.txt

echo "This is message body" | mail -s "This is Subject" your_email@example.com
```

If you would like to be notified when every smaller job is finished, then you can use the command `mail` after the command `lpr` and before the command `sleep`.

Comment: Adding sleeping gaps is not a bad idea at all. However, is there be a way to check if `lpr` is finished with the previous job (and only my job)?

Comment: @UndeadKernel. Very nice question. It depends on how you want to be notified. For example, you can use the command mailx after the last line in the previous code to receive a notification email once printing is completed. Please see the updated answer!

Comment: I was thinking more in the direction of replacing the `sleep` command for something that regularly checks if a print job is finished :D

Comment: Receiving a text message for example?

Comment: More like waiting in the script for a mini-job to complete rather than sleeping arbitrarily for some seconds.